# Is it possible to extend the Service Fabric Explorer with custom UI?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I don't see any documented plugin framework for extending the functionality of the Service Fabric Explorer. Is there perhaps an undocumented one (or some samples), which I can use to add custom actions / information to my services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFX does not contain a feature like this, but the source is available online on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/service-fabric-explorer) though, you could either:

- Request as a feature and wait to be accepted and implemented by someone
- Fork the code and implement yourself, and maybe submit back to upstream repository.

Comment: I see. I can have my cluster host a parallel copy of the SFX that I modify, and leave the default copy (that runs on port 19080 untouched). Makes sense. Thanks!